# Understanding linux kernel and patches releases

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I would like to better understand how linux kernel / patches releases work.

For example, if I open www.kernel.org today (Dec 12, 2013) the main download (yellow button) takes me to "linux-3.12.5.tar.xx" that is the latest stable. This is clear.

But if I move into "https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/", I can find (among many archives):

(1) linux-3.12.tar.gz

(2) patch-3.12.5.gz

(3) patch-3.12.gz

So the first question: is "linux-3.12.5" = (1)linux-3.12 "+" (2)patch-3.12.5?

If so, what is "patch-3.12"(3) for ? is "linux-3.12" = linux-3.11 "+" (3)patch-3.12 like above?

Thanks!

Comment: You apply a patch to get from the *previous* version to this version. So linux-3.12.4 + patch-3.12.5 = linux-3.12.5. For 3.12, previous is 3.11, not 3.11.999 or whatever. For 3.11.1 previous is 3.11 too.

Comment: @n.m. so imagine I have linux-3.12 archive, if I want to get linux-3.12.5, I have to apply all of this patches: patch-3.12.1, patch-3.12.2, patch-3.12.3, patch-3.12.4, patch-3.12.5? (of course unless I download linux-3.12.5 archive directly :) ). So if I only apply patch-3.12.5 to linux-3.12 I won't get linux-3.12.5, right?

Comment: Yes you have to apply several patches. If you try to apply 3.12.5 to 3.12 it will probably fail. Look at the patch sizes, they are another ndication of that.

Comment: ...mmm some other guys told me the oppisite: all the patches apply on the same level, so linux-3.12.5 = linux-3.12 + patch-3.12.5... I just looked in https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ and patch-3.12.5 >(bigger than) patch-3.12.4 > patch-3.12.3 > patch-3.12.2 > patch-3.12.1. I also tried appliyng patch patch-3.12.5 to linux-3.12 and I had success... so, who's right?

Comment: Please look [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/applying-patches.txt) or [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/36-how-to-patch-a-linux-kernel/). If this has changed in the 3 series I know nothing about it :( Also on't know why the size grows, but look at the x.y path sizes vs x.y.z sizes --- x.y are much larger and they *don'* grow monotonically. Have no idea what that means. I'll have to compare the patches themselves.

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like the things did change considerably in the 3 series (or perhaps with the move to git). The patches to the 3 series are indeed not incremental! https://github.com/torvalds/linux Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/README (line 95 onward):

> Unlike patches for the 3.x kernels, patches for the 3.x.y kernels
>   (also known as the -stable kernels) are not incremental but instead
>   apply directly to the base 3.x kernel.  For example, if your base
>   kernel is 3.0 and you want to apply the 3.0.3 patch, you must not
>   first apply the 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 patches. Similarly, if you are running
>   kernel version 3.0.2 and want to jump to 3.0.3, you must first reverse
>   the 3.0.2 patch (that is, patch -R) *before* applying the 3.0.3 patch.
>   You can read more on this in Documentation/applying-patches.txt

Thanks to n.m. for linking source!